# Is it possible to fetch values using smarty, php, JQuery from another page ? [ No Cross-domains ]

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I am working on smarty template files.

core php of that template engine are encoded with ioncube.

So I am **restricted** to get certain values on certain pages only.

For Example,

I get value of `{$clientemail}` only  on **clientareadetails.php**

on **clientprofile.php** value of `{$clientemail}` is *null*

So, Is it possible to fetch values using **smarty, php, JQuery** from another page ?

All my pages are residing on single domain only.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Thank You!**

Comment: Please describe in more detail where `$clientemail` comes from.

Comment: @Pekka : $clientemail is user-entered value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign all needed variables to Smarty from the PHP end. Don't use Ajax for this.

If `$clientemail` is a fixed value in your script, the best way would be to keep a central configuration array with all values in a PHP file, including that file in every script instance (`include "conf.php"`), and passing that array as a Smarty variable.

```
 $conf = array();
 $conf["clientemail"] = "xyz@domain.com";

 ...........

 $Smarty = new Smarty();  // or whichever way you do it
 $Smarty->assign("conf", $conf);

 ............

 Then in the template:
 {$conf.clientemail}
```

If `$clientemail` is a user-entered value, you could store it in `$_SESSION` (if you have a session running) and fetch it:

```
 In the PHP script that processes the form:
 $_SESSION["clientemail"] = ..... wherever clientemail comes from

 ...........

 $Smarty = new Smarty();  // or whichever way you do it
 $Smarty->assign("clientemail", $_SESSION["clientemail"]);

 ............

 Then in the template:
 {$clientemail}
```

Note that this example will give you trouble if the user has two or more windows open and is filling out the same form at the same time: `$_SESSION["clientemail"]` would be overwritten by each form submission.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Doing that via ajax is super lame.